# Does MySQL JDBC version have to match the server

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Should I use the same jdbc driver version as the server? I want to use AWS Aurora which is compatible with MySQL 5.6. Do I have to use mysql driver 5.6.x, or can I use the latest 8.0.x?

Comment: There is no MySQL Connector/J 5.6 (there is 5.1.x (and older) and 8.0.x), so that should at least answer the question that the version of the driver does not have to match the version of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/8.0.html):

> MySQL Connector/J 8.0 is highly recommended for use with MySQL Server 8.0, 5.7, 5.6, and 5.5. Please upgrade to MySQL Connector/J 8.0.

So yes, you can use the latest version and actually is highly recommended.